# JAVA - How can I make sure program only continues with a scanned int?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, do-while

I'm learning to program in Java and I'm working on a pizza-ordering console program.

I've gotten the entire program to work, but I want to fool-proof it. Three places I ask for an int input, but when I type a char or a string, the program crashes.

**What I hoped to achieve:**

- When the user enters a valid number, the program continues - Done
- **When the user enters a char or a string they get an error message and the loop starts over.**

Here's an example from my code:

```
do {
            correctInput = true;
            System.out.println("Step 1: Look through the menu below and type in the NUMBER of the pizza you want.\n"); 

            pizzaMenu();
            System.out.print("\nType in your pizza number here: ");
            pizzaNumber = pizza.nextInt();
            pizza.nextLine();
            switch (pizzaNumber) {
                case 1:
                    pizzaChoice = "Napoli";
                    pizzaPrice = 50;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pizzaChoice = "Hawaii";
                    pizzaPrice = 50;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pizzaChoice = "Quattro Stagioni";
                    pizzaPrice = 60;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pizzaChoice = "Sicillia";
                    pizzaPrice = 75;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pizzaChoice = "Turbo";
                    pizzaPrice = 60;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pizzaChoice = "Jamaica";
                    pizzaPrice = 75;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    pizzaChoice = "Romano";
                    pizzaPrice = 60;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pizzaChoice = "Vulcano";
                    pizzaPrice = 75;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    pizzaChoice = "Vegetariana";
                    pizzaPrice = 60;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    pizzaChoice = "Salame";
                    pizzaPrice = 60;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You've entered a wrong number. Try again");
                    correctInput = false;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!correctInput);
```

Could you please help pointing me towards a possible solution?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Couldn't find it on my own, but there happens to be a good answer on the same question somewhere else. Thank everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a string from the scanner and then manually try to convert it to required number (either `Integer` or `Double`):

```
String str = scan.next();

if (isNumeric(str))
    System.out.println("Numeric value: " + Double.parseDouble(str));
else
    System.out.println("Not a numeric");
```

And method that checks if given string a numeric or not:

```
private static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(str);
        return true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```